Firebase Cloud Function Deploy is failing with different Messages
My Firebase Project has been running for a year now. Today morning I was working on a few functions and Firebase Deploy has been working perfect. I use Firebase CLI to upload functions. I use Firebase Functions V1.
I had made no changes to my project environment, did not update firebase tools or npm. But suddenly functions don't deploy. I have been getting various error messages. Also I can see that some error is about functions V1 and some about V2.:

Error: Failed to make request to https://cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/v2/projects/*****/locations/-/functions?filter=environment%3D%22GEN_2%22

Error: Failed to get Firebase project ******. Please make sure the project exists and your account has permission to access it.

Error: Failed to make request to https://serviceusage.googleapis.com/v1/projects/****/services/cloudbuild.googleapis.com


I have tried logging out and login back in. But does not help.
I updated firebase tools. Does not help
My updated Firebase version: 13.10.1
NPM Version: 9.5.0

Suddenly things are working fine. Without me making any change. So it looks like a problem in transition at Firebase's end

Good to hear it was an ephemeral problem, oTwo.

@oTwo, please post what steps you perform so that other community members with similar issues could find this helpful.

Posting as per comment of @oTwo:

Suddenly things are working fine. Without me making any change. So it looks like a problem in transition at Firebase's end.


It really helps. However, in my case, it took 2 hours for a successful deployment to occur. During those 2 hours, the error messages were inconsistent, and the process failed at different stages. Therefore, it’s best to wait a couple of hours before diving into debugging.
